# AWS SES - Bounced emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I will try to express my question, I'm sorry if is not the correct way to do it.

I have an AWS SES configured to receive emails from my customers, sometimes the client get in a list and try to send an email too large (above 10MB), and my costumer start to receive bounced emails from all recipients in that list.

The bounce happens when my client tries to send an email for another people but the email of my company appears on CC field.

E.g:

the client sent an email:

TO: wherever@google.com
CC: mycompany@mycompany.com (this one will be sent for my SES); [a lot of other emails.........list]

This mail will be more large than 10MB (my SES must have to treat it).

This chain wil generate an bounced mail for my costumer, once that my email appears on CC list.

It's a little bit complex to express, but basicaly is it.

I'd like to know if is possible to track this attempts when the costumer receive the first bounce email from AWS. and to trigger a alert for me that the costumer is getting in a bounced list.

Comment: I think what you are asking is this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely do this, SES supports notifications per type to SNS. The types are `Delivery`, `Bounce`, `Complaint`.

Each type can be registered to an [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) topic which you can subscribe a Lambda function to.

This [Lambda function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) can then perform any logical decisions that you would like for your workflow.

In addition you can [subscribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html) any email addresses you want to receive the raw notification that it was undelivered, although you will need to confirm there subscriptions before they can receive notifications. This would be ideal for a support inbox for example.

The AWS documentation contains more information about [notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity-using-notifications.html)

Comment: Hi Chris, this approach which you said, is good to send emails, in my case, i've receiving email and storing them on my S3, when someone goes to send an mail for me, I've to treat it and start an alert that a bounce mail was generated throught it.

Comment: So the bounce is not from your sending the email? But from someone else instead?

Comment: Yes, the bounce happens when my client tries to send an email for another people but the email of my company appears on CC field.

E.g:

the client sent an email:

TO: wherever@google.com
CC: mycompany@mycompany.com (this one will be sent for my SES); [a lot of other emails.........]
This mail will be more large than 10MB (my SES must have to treat it).

This chain wil generate an bounced mail for my costumer, once that my email appears on CC list.

It's a little bit complex to express, but basicaly is it.

Comment: Hmm, SES does not have reporting for bounces to your inbox as the service rejects before it passes through, this is likely something that they would need to implement

Comment: Oh, thats nice to know, I've been broken my head to solve it during all day.

Comment: Yeah I can imagine thats a bit annoying :(

Comment: Glad this is answered for you @DougP, did the notifications help much?